# How to configure the stylelint extension in vscode?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, create-react-app, stylelint

I created a project using the `create-react-app --template typescript`. Now I wanted to try out the `css` linter `stylelint`. And, so I have installed the npm packages `stylelint` and  `stylelint-config-standard` as **dev dependency** using `yarn`.

I have also added a config file named **.stylelintrc.js** with below content

```
module.exports = {
  extends: "stylelint-config-standard",
  ignoreFiles: ["./build/**/*.css", "./node_modules/**/*.css", "**/*.js",
  "**/*.jsx"],
}
```

In my **package.json**, I have also added a script like

```
"css-lint": "stylelint '*/**/*.css'",
```

Now when I run `yarn css-lint` in the terminal, it works.

As for VS Code, I installed and enabled the [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stylelint.vscode-stylelint). And as suggested, **I have disabled the default css, less, sass linters**. I have also restarted the VS code but no luck, the **stylelint extension does not work or highlight any errors in VS code**.

I am stuck. And any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi! I am a bit late, but maybe can help someone else. Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69149058/why-the-stylelint-vscode-extension-is-not-working-on-my-computer/71817658#71817658

Answer (score 2):

Add the language identifiers for the documents you want to validate to the extension's workspace or user settings using the [stylelint.validate](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stylelint.vscode-stylelint#stylelintvalidate) option. Troubleshoot vscode-stylelint with the output panel/channel.

```json
//.vscode/settings.json
{
  "stylelint.validate": [
    "css",
    "scss",
    ...
  ],
}
```

[image]